# difference when binding a Label and a TextBox (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Just found out something that I am very surprised with.

XAML code:

```
  <Label  Content="{Binding myParameter}"/>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding myParameter}" />
```

myParameter is an instance of a class whose ToString() method is overridden:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Displaying value: " + Name);
    return Name;
}
```

When rendering:
 the label invokes ToString() and displays the Name property.
 the TextBox does not display anything

Can I get some explanation why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content` is expected to be any object, which means that `ToString()` will be called.

`Text` is expected to be a String property. If `Text` is not bound to a String property, then the framework error handling kicks in and it displays nothing.

The best practice is to bind directly to the values you wish to display, rather than a parent object. In this case, bind to the `Name` property, directly.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Textbox Documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) `TextBox.Text` Property is of type `string` :

```
public string Text { get; set; }
```

and as per [Label documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) `Label.Content` Property is of type `object` :

```
public object Content { get; set; }
```

Hence assigning some value to `TextBox.Text` will not call the `ToString()` method that you have overridden, since it is already of type `string`. `Label.Content` calls the method since the object is being converted to string.